# cocoapods setup an error: Error loading the plugin

Tags: installation, plugins, cocoapods

pod setup

---

Error loading the plugin `cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.5`.

### NoMethodError - undefined method `activate' for #<Gem::StubSpecification:0x00007f95cb03a940 @extension_dir=nil, @full_gem_path="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.5", @gem_dir=nil, @ignored=nil, @loaded_from="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/specifications/cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.5.gemspec", @data=#<Gem::StubSpecification::StubLine:0x00007f95cd8bea38 @name="cocoapods-deintegrate", @version=#<Gem::Version "1.0.5">, @platform="ruby", @extensions=[], @full_name="cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.5", @require_paths=["lib"]>, @name=nil, @spec=#<Gem::Specification:0x00007f95cb0f8af8 @extension_dir=nil, @full_gem_path="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.5", @gem_dir=nil, @ignored=nil, @bin_dir=nil, @cache_dir=nil, @cache_file=nil, @doc_dir=nil, @ri_dir=nil, @spec_dir=nil, @spec_file=nil, @gems_dir="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems", @base_dir="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0", @loaded=true, @activated=true, @loaded_from="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/specifications/cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.5.gemspec", @original_platform=nil, @installed_by_version=#<Gem::Version "3.4.15">, @autorequire=nil, @date=2021-08-16 00:00:00 UTC, @description=nil, @email=["kyle@fuller.li"], @homepage="https://github.com/kylef/cocoapods-deintegrate", @name="cocoapods-deintegrate", @post_install_message=nil, @signing_key=nil, @summary="A CocoaPods plugin to remove and de-integrate CocoaPods from your project.", @version=#<Gem::Version "1.0.5">, @authors=["Kyle Fuller"], @bindir="bin", @cert_chain=[], @dependencies=[], @executables=[], @extensions=[], @extra_rdoc_files=[], @files=[], @licenses=["MIT"], @metadata={}, @platform="ruby", @rdoc_options=[], @require_paths=["lib"], @required_ruby_version=#<Gem::Requirement:0x00007f95cb049990 @requirements=[[">=", #<Gem::Version "2.0.0">]]>, @required_rubygems_version=#<Gem::Requirement:0x00007f95cb063ac0 @requirements=[[">=", #<Gem::Version "0">]]>, @requirements=[], @rubygems_version="3.4.15", @specification_version=4, @test_files=[], @new_platform="ruby", @full_name="cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.5", @full_require_paths=["/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.5/lib"] cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.5>, @base_dir="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0", @gems_dir="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems", @default_gem=false, @activated=true> Did you mean?  activated? /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:93:in` safe_activate_and_require'
/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:31:in `block in load_plugins' /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:30:in` map'
/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:30:in `load_plugins' /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:326:in` block in run'
/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:325:in `each' /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:325:in` run'
/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run' /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:55:in` <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:25:in `load' /usr/local/bin/pod:25:in` '
/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval' /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in` '

---

Error loading the plugin `cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0`.

### NoMethodError - undefined method `activate' for #<Gem::StubSpecification:0x00007f95cb03a508 @extension_dir=nil, @full_gem_path="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0", @gem_dir=nil, @ignored=nil, @loaded_from="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/specifications/cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0.gemspec", @data=#<Gem::StubSpecification::StubLine:0x00007f95cd8bda98 @name="cocoapods-plugins", @version=#<Gem::Version "1.0.0">, @platform="ruby", @extensions=[], @full_name="cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0", @require_paths=["lib"]>, @name=nil, @spec=#<Gem::Specification:0x00007f95bc075270 @extension_dir=nil, @full_gem_path="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0", @gem_dir=nil, @ignored=nil, @bin_dir=nil, @cache_dir=nil, @cache_file=nil, @doc_dir=nil, @ri_dir=nil, @spec_dir=nil, @spec_file=nil, @gems_dir="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems", @base_dir="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0", @loaded=true, @activated=true, @loaded_from="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/specifications/cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0.gemspec", @original_platform=nil, @installed_by_version=#<Gem::Version "3.4.15">, @autorequire=nil, @date=2016-05-10 00:00:00 UTC, @description="                         This CocoaPods plugin shows information about all available CocoaPods plugins\n                         (yes, this is very meta!).\n                         This CP plugin adds the \"pod plugins\" command to CocoaPods so that you can list\n                         all plugins (registered in the reference JSON hosted at CocoaPods/cocoapods-plugins)\n", @email=nil, @homepage="https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods-plugins", @name="cocoapods-plugins", @post_install_message=nil, @signing_key=nil, @summary="CocoaPods plugin which shows info about available CocoaPods plugins.", @version=#<Gem::Version "1.0.0">, @authors=["David Grandinetti", "Olivier Halligon"], @bindir="bin", @cert_chain=[], @dependencies=[<Gem::Dependency type=:runtime name="nap" requirements=">= 0">, <Gem::Dependency type=:development name="bundler" requirements="~> 1.3">, <Gem::Dependency type=:development name="rake" requirements=">= 0">], @executables=[], @extensions=[], @extra_rdoc_files=[], @files=[], @licenses=["MIT"], @metadata={}, @platform="ruby", @rdoc_options=[], @require_paths=["lib"], @required_ruby_version=#<Gem::Requirement:0x00007f95bc074488 @requirements=[[">=", #<Gem::Version "2.0.0">]]>, @required_rubygems_version=#<Gem::Requirement:0x00007f95bc074c08 @requirements=[[">=", #<Gem::Version "0">]]>, @requirements=[], @rubygems_version="3.4.15", @specification_version=4, @test_files=[], @new_platform="ruby", @full_name="cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0", @full_require_paths=["/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0/lib"] cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0>, @base_dir="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0", @gems_dir="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems", @default_gem=false, @activated=true> Did you mean?  activated? /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:93:in` safe_activate_and_require'
/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:31:in `block in load_plugins' /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:30:in` map'
/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:30:in `load_plugins' /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:326:in` block in run'
/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:325:in `each' /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:325:in` run'
/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run' /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:55:in` <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:25:in `load' /usr/local/bin/pod:25:in` '
/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval' /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in` '

---

Error loading the plugin `cocoapods-search-1.0.1`.

### NoMethodError - undefined method `activate' for #<Gem::StubSpecification:0x00007f95cb03a4b8 @extension_dir=nil, @full_gem_path="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-search-1.0.1", @gem_dir=nil, @ignored=nil, @loaded_from="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/specifications/cocoapods-search-1.0.1.gemspec", @data=#<Gem::StubSpecification::StubLine:0x00007f95cd8bd390 @name="cocoapods-search", @version=#<Gem::Version "1.0.1">, @platform="ruby", @extensions=[], @full_name="cocoapods-search-1.0.1", @require_paths=["lib"]>, @name=nil, @spec=#<Gem::Specification:0x00007f95bc06d480 @extension_dir=nil, @full_gem_path="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-search-1.0.1", @gem_dir=nil, @ignored=nil, @bin_dir=nil, @cache_dir=nil, @cache_file=nil, @doc_dir=nil, @ri_dir=nil, @spec_dir=nil, @spec_file=nil, @gems_dir="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems", @base_dir="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0", @loaded=true, @activated=true, @loaded_from="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/specifications/cocoapods-search-1.0.1.gemspec", @original_platform=nil, @installed_by_version=#<Gem::Version "3.4.15">, @autorequire=nil, @date=2021-08-13 00:00:00 UTC, @description="Search for pods.", @email=["eloy.de.enige@gmail.com", "fabiopelosin@gmail.com", "emkosz@gmail.com"], @homepage="https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-search", @name="cocoapods-search", @post_install_message=nil, @signing_key=nil, @summary="Searches for pods, ignoring case, whose name matches` QUERY`. If the` --full`option is specified, this will also search in the summary and description of the pods.", @version=#<Gem::Version "1.0.1">, @authors=["Eloy Durán", "Fabio Pelosin", "Emma Koszinowski"], @bindir="bin", @cert_chain=[], @dependencies=[<Gem::Dependency type=:development name="bundler" requirements="~> 1.3">, <Gem::Dependency type=:development name="rake" requirements=">= 0">], @executables=[], @extensions=[], @extra_rdoc_files=[], @files=[], @licenses=["MIT"], @metadata={}, @platform="ruby", @rdoc_options=[], @require_paths=["lib"], @required_ruby_version=#<Gem::Requirement:0x00007f95bc06d2a0 @requirements=[[">=", #<Gem::Version "0">]]>, @required_rubygems_version=#<Gem::Requirement:0x00007f95bc06d110 @requirements=[[">=", #<Gem::Version "0">]]>, @requirements=[], @rubygems_version="3.4.15", @specification_version=4, @test_files=[], @new_platform="ruby", @full_name="cocoapods-search-1.0.1", @full_require_paths=["/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-search-1.0.1/lib"] cocoapods-search-1.0.1>, @base_dir="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0", @gems_dir="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems", @default_gem=false, @activated=true> Did you mean?  activated? /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:93:in`safe_activate_and_require'
/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:31:in `block in load_plugins' /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:30:in` map'
/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:30:in `load_plugins' /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:326:in` block in run'
/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:325:in `each' /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:325:in` run'
/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run' /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:55:in` <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:25:in `load' /usr/local/bin/pod:25:in` '
/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval' /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in` '

---

Error loading the plugin `cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0`.

### NoMethodError - undefined method `activate' for #<Gem::StubSpecification:0x00007f95cb03a440 @extension_dir=nil, @full_gem_path="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0", @gem_dir=nil, @ignored=nil, @loaded_from="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/specifications/cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0.gemspec", @data=#<Gem::StubSpecification::StubLine:0x00007f95cd8bc800 @name="cocoapods-trunk", @version=#<Gem::Version "1.6.0">, @platform="ruby", @extensions=[], @full_name="cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0", @require_paths=["lib"]>, @name=nil, @spec=#<Gem::Specification:0x00007f95bc067058 @extension_dir=nil, @full_gem_path="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0", @gem_dir=nil, @ignored=nil, @bin_dir=nil, @cache_dir=nil, @cache_file=nil, @doc_dir=nil, @ri_dir=nil, @spec_dir=nil, @spec_file=nil, @gems_dir="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems", @base_dir="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0", @loaded=true, @activated=true, @loaded_from="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/specifications/cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0.gemspec", @original_platform=nil, @installed_by_version=#<Gem::Version "3.4.15">, @autorequire=nil, @date=2021-09-01 00:00:00 UTC, @description=nil, @email=["eloy.de.enige@gmail.com"], @homepage="https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-trunk", @name="cocoapods-trunk", @post_install_message=nil, @signing_key=nil, @summary="Interact with trunk.cocoapods.org", @version=#<Gem::Version "1.6.0">, @authors=["Eloy Durán"], @bindir="bin", @cert_chain=[], @dependencies=[<Gem::Dependency type=:runtime name="nap" requirements=">= 0.8, < 2.0">, <Gem::Dependency type=:runtime name="netrc" requirements="~> 0.11">, <Gem::Dependency type=:development name="bundler" requirements="~> 1.3">, <Gem::Dependency type=:development name="rake" requirements="~> 10.0">], @executables=[], @extensions=[], @extra_rdoc_files=[], @files=[], @licenses=["MIT"], @metadata={}, @platform="ruby", @rdoc_options=[], @require_paths=["lib"], @required_ruby_version=#<Gem::Requirement:0x00007f95bc066658 @requirements=[[">=", #<Gem::Version "2.0.0">]]>, @required_rubygems_version=#<Gem::Requirement:0x00007f95bc066cc0 @requirements=[[">=", #<Gem::Version "0">]]>, @requirements=[], @rubygems_version="3.4.15", @specification_version=4, @test_files=[], @new_platform="ruby", @full_name="cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0", @full_require_paths=["/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0/lib"] cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0>, @base_dir="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0", @gems_dir="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems", @default_gem=false, @activated=true> Did you mean?  activated? /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:93:in` safe_activate_and_require'
/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:31:in `block in load_plugins' /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:30:in` map'
/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:30:in `load_plugins' /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:326:in` block in run'
/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:325:in `each' /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:325:in` run'
/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run' /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:55:in` <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:25:in `load' /usr/local/bin/pod:25:in` '
/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval' /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in` '

---

Error loading the plugin `cocoapods-try-1.2.0`.

### NoMethodError - undefined method `activate' for #<Gem::StubSpecification:0x00007f95cb03a378 @extension_dir=nil, @full_gem_path="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-try-1.2.0", @gem_dir=nil, @ignored=nil, @loaded_from="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/specifications/cocoapods-try-1.2.0.gemspec", @data=#<Gem::StubSpecification::StubLine:0x00007f95cd8b78a0 @name="cocoapods-try", @version=#<Gem::Version "1.2.0">, @platform="ruby", @extensions=[], @full_name="cocoapods-try-1.2.0", @require_paths=["lib"]>, @name=nil, @spec=#<Gem::Specification:0x00007f95bc057c98 @extension_dir=nil, @full_gem_path="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-try-1.2.0", @gem_dir=nil, @ignored=nil, @bin_dir=nil, @cache_dir=nil, @cache_file=nil, @doc_dir=nil, @ri_dir=nil, @spec_dir=nil, @spec_file=nil, @gems_dir="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems", @base_dir="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0", @loaded=true, @activated=true, @loaded_from="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/specifications/cocoapods-try-1.2.0.gemspec", @original_platform=nil, @installed_by_version=#<Gem::Version "3.4.15">, @autorequire=nil, @date=2020-04-20 00:00:00 UTC, @description=nil, @email=nil, @homepage="https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods-try", @name="cocoapods-try", @post_install_message=nil, @signing_key=nil, @summary="CocoaPods plugin which allows to quickly try the demo project of a Pod.", @version=#<Gem::Version "1.2.0">, @authors=["Fabio Pelosin"], @bindir="bin", @cert_chain=[], @dependencies=[<Gem::Dependency type=:development name="bundler" requirements="~> 1.3">, <Gem::Dependency type=:development name="rake" requirements="~> 10.0">], @executables=[], @extensions=[], @extra_rdoc_files=[], @files=[], @licenses=["MIT"], @metadata={}, @platform="ruby", @rdoc_options=[], @require_paths=["lib"], @required_ruby_version=#<Gem::Requirement:0x00007f95bc0579f0 @requirements=[[">=", #<Gem::Version "0">]]>, @required_rubygems_version=#<Gem::Requirement:0x00007f95bc057860 @requirements=[[">=", #<Gem::Version "0">]]>, @requirements=[], @rubygems_version="3.4.15", @specification_version=4, @test_files=[], @new_platform="ruby", @full_name="cocoapods-try-1.2.0", @full_require_paths=["/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-try-1.2.0/lib"] cocoapods-try-1.2.0>, @base_dir="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0", @gems_dir="/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems", @default_gem=false, @activated=true> Did you mean?  activated? /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:93:in` safe_activate_and_require'
/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:31:in `block in load_plugins' /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:30:in` map'
/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:30:in `load_plugins' /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:326:in` block in run'
/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:325:in `each' /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:325:in` run'
/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run' /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:55:in` <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:25:in `load' /usr/local/bin/pod:25:in` '
/Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval' /Users/kaizhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in` '

pod setup
error!!!
how to solve!

Answer (score 1):

### I solved this by exist:
gem install claide -v 1.1.0

thans from  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11134

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have no clue whats this claide is or does but this also fixed this issue for me. thanks

Comment: ok found what this is here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CLAide